# Easiest way to get pip on python 2.3.4 server

Tags: python, python-2.3

I'm working on a server with python 2.3.4 and cannot upgrade it. I don't have setuptools (and therefore easy_install), which I need to install pip. Looking through the [easy_install docs](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html) it looks like you need 2.3.5 to be able to use easy_install. Is there a way around this? I really just want pip to work on this server.

Comment: What's your assessment of the costs of upgrading the python to at least python 2.3.5?

Comment: It's pretty much out of my hands. Other departments need that version for very old programs, which would need to be rebuilt if there was an upgrade. I'm basically trying to get a virtualenv on this server so I can install python 2.7 in a virtenv to run programs that rely on a newer version of python.

Comment: Can you just compile and install latest python2.7 from sources, and ignore the obsolete python2.3 all-together?

Comment: I am not the OP, but I have the same problem. I can't easily compile from source, because the server was set up without a compiler. I'd have to download GCC plus all the other GNU tools (automake/autoconf/linker/etc) from source, and it would be an exercise in yak shaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. From the PIP docs:

```
pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 and also pypy.

pip works on Unix/Linux, OS X, and Windows.

Note: Python 2.5 was supported through v1.3.1, and Python 2.4 was supported through v1.1.
```

No mentions of 2.3 anywhere. You can however try the get-pip.py script from their [install docs page](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip).

Comment: I have the same situation. The get-pip.py script doesn't work with Python 2.3.4. Apparently multi-line string literals weren't supported back then.